# Unrecognized selector sent to instance: key-value pair

Tags: objective-c, xcode, key-value

I get

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM metadata]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd0b6250'
```

when i reach and execute this part of my code:

```
IDTherapyMetadata* meta = [self.dataCon getMetaDataFromId:content.metadata];
```

the method in dataCon looks like this:

```
-(IDTherapyMetadata*)getMetaDataFromId:(NSString*)metaDataId
{
for (IDTherapyMetadata* metadata in self.parser.metadata)
{
    if([metaDataId compare:metadata.objId] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        return metadata;
    }
}
return nil;
```

}

The strange thing is, if I write

```
IDTherapyMetadata* meta = [self.dataCon getMetaDataFromId:[content valueForKey:@"metadata"]];
```

instead it works just fine.

However I want to be able to use dotnotation and looking through apple's documentation
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html
 haven't helped me.

Why i'm I getting this behaviour and how do I fix it?

Any help is greatly appreciated

EDIT:
The code for IDTherapyContents.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface IDTherapyContents : NSObject 
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* urlId;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* url;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* type;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* timestamp;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* metadata;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* lang;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* objId;

//methods
-(id)initWithJsonDic:(NSDictionary*)jsonDic;

@end
```

Code for IDTherpayMetaData.h

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "IDTherapyImages.h"

@interface IDTherapyMetadata : NSObject 

//Array contains 'String' objects
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray* thumbnails;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* title;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* timestamp;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* subCategory;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* lang;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* objId;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* description5;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* description4;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* description3;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* description2;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* description1;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* category;

//Array contains 'IDTherapyImages' objects
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray* images;

//methods
-(id)initWithJsonDic:(NSDictionary*)jsonDic;

@end
```

Code for IDTherapyProducts.h:

```
@interface IDTherapyProducts : NSObject 

//Array contains 'String' objects
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray* contents;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* uniqueId;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* timestamp;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* price;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* posted;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* normalPrice;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* metadata;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* lang;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* objId;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString* badge;

//methods
-(id)initWithJsonDic:(NSDictionary*)jsonDic;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple case of confusing properties with KVC.  They are different things.

`content.metadata` is nothing more than syntactic sugar for `[content metadata]`.  So you need a method on `content` called `-metadata` and as `content` is an `NSDictionary` that method doesn't exist.  So that's why the exception is thrown.

On any normal object `[content valueForKey: @"metadata"]` would also throw an exception because KVC looks for a method with that name.  However, on `NSDictionary` `-valueForKey:` is overridden to call `-objectForKey:` unless the key starts with an `@` in which case the `@` is stripped and `[super valueForKey: ...]` is invoked.

> However I want to be able to use dotnotation

Then you need a method on `NSDictionary` called `-metadata`.  You could use a category.

```
@interface NSDictionary(MyMetadataExtension)

-(id) metadata;

@end

@implementation NSDictionary(MyMetadataExtension)

-(id) metadata
{
    return [self objectForKey: @"metadata"];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you come to the conclusion that `content` is an `NSDictionary` when it is a `IDTherapyContents` object?

Comment: Because of the error message you reported `'-[__NSDictionaryM metadata]: unrecognized selector`